# Linear programming using the spicy.optimize.linprog

Tags: scipy, linear-programming

I’m trying to formulate and solve a linear programming problem using the [spicy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) function.

I want to solve the function Ax = b subject to the following constraints:

```
# A                      b   
-0.4866 x1 + 0.1632 x2 < 0  
 0.3211 x1 + 0.5485 x2 < 0  
-0.5670 x1 + 0.1099 x2 < 0   
-0.1070 x1 + 0.0545 x2 = 1   
-0.4379 x1 + 0.1465 x2 < 0   
 0.0220 x1 + 0.7960 x2 < 0  
-0.3673 x1 - 0.0494 x2 < 0
```

I have as input an nx2 matrix `A` and nx1 matrix `b`.  The result should be the vectors x1 and x2.  Here's my input data.

```
# Coefficients

A = [[-0.4866, 0.1632],   
     [0.3211, 0.5485],   
     [-0.5670, 0.1099],   
     [-0.1070, 0.0545],   
     [-0.4379, 0.1465],   
     [0.0220, 0.7960],  
     [-0.3673, -0.0494]]  

# Inequalities

b = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I think my problem is how to formulate `c`, the function the be minimized for input into the `linprog` function.

```
res = linprog(c, A, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve for the upper bounds by:

```
c = [1, 0, 0]

A = [[-1, -0.486, 0.1632],
     [-1, 0.3211, 0.5485], 
     [-1, -0.5670, 0.1099], 
     [-1, -0.1070, 0.0545], 
     [-1, -0.4379, 0.1465], 
     [-1, 0.220, 0.7960],
     [-1,-0.3673, -0.0494]]

b = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0]

c0_bounds = (0, 1)
x1_bounds = (-np.inf, np.inf)
x2_bounds = (-np.inf, np.inf)

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(c0_bounds, x1_bounds, x2_bounds), options={"disp": True})
```

But now what if I also want to solve for the **lower bounds**?

Comment: Seems like one way to find the lower bound is flip the signs in the last 2 columns of A.